# Detect via Facebook event when permissions have changed after initial login

Tags: javascript, facebook, permissions

I have an app that allows a user to post a comment.  Near the comment textbox I provide a checkbox labeled “Also post to my wall”.  When the user clicks the submit button I check to see if they are logged into FB. If yes I try to authorize my app.  Sometimes the user does not want to post to their wall and so if they leave that checkbox empty I do not ask for publish permissions. Then, sometimes in that same session a user tries to post another comment, but this time DOES want to post to their wall.  I can detect that I do not have the publish permission and if that’s the case I call FB.login again with the extended permission.  The trouble I am running into is that NO event seems to be fired after this second login, regardless of whether the user now allows the publish permission or not.

Here are the events I’m watching:

auth.login
auth.prompt
auth.statusChange
auth.authResponseChange

I am currently using the Javascript SDK

If I can’t get an event I am not sure how to watch for the permissions dialog closing so I can recheck permissions and post to their wall.

Comment: There has to be a way to always increase your permission and simply NOT published on the wall if the user chooses not to publish that comment.